# Proving that every symmetric matrix is congruent to the following canonical form

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, matrix-decomposition

> Let $B\bf $ be a real symmetric matrix of order $n\times n$. Then show that there exists an invertible matrix $\bf P$ such that $\bf P'AP=\begin{pmatrix}\bf I & \bf0 & \bf0 \\\bf0 & \bf-I & \bf0 \\\bf0 & \bf0 & \bf0* \\\end{pmatrix}$; $\bf I$ and $\bf-I$ denote the number of 1s and -1s in the diagonal and $\bf0*$ denotes the number of 0s.

I seriously have no idea now to begin this proof and cannot find any resources online which state the proof.

Can anyone help me out or redirect me to the proof?

Comment: $I$ and $-I$ are matrices. They cannot denote numbers. And you might google on “inertia” of symmetric matrices.

Answer (score 4):

This is a basic result called *[Sylvester's law of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia)*. You can find the proof in any good book on Linear Algebra. See for instance

J. J. Rotman, *Advanced Modern Algebra* (second edition), Theorem 8.84 p. 692.

Comment: algorithm that gets as far as diagonal, after which one may use a final diagonal $P_{k+1}$ (with some square roots) to reach $\pm 1.$ Did this one yesterday:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2495163/quadratic-forms-completing-squares/2495265#2495265

Comment: also first edition Rotman, page 704 Theorem 9.83